# NSDateFormatter dateFromString wrong result?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get an `NSDate` object from an `NSString`. The problem is that, I'm `losing` 1 day in the process.

This is the `NSString`: `2015-08-01`, and here is the code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *result = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

The `result` turns out to be `2015-07-31 21:00:00 +0000`.

How so? I don't understand. Besides, where did the `21:00:00` come from? I'm getting this same result regardless of running the code on a real device or simulator.

Any idea why ? I'm suspecting a `timezone` issue. However, I'm getting the `dateString` in `UTC` format, and I'm not altering it. Thoughts?

Comment: You are seeing the difference between your local time and the UTC time used when logging an `NSDate`. What you are seeing is correct. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with time zone.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

Comment: Do not do this unless you really want to parse the date as a UTC date instead of a local date.

Answer (score 1):

Setting time zone  will do the trick

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-08-01";
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *result = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```